# Entity Framework tracks records as deleted without removing

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following code. I only query data and do not remove or delete entities, but EF tracks the record as deleted. I don't understand why.

````
List<SubscriptionModuleDto> subscriptionModuleDtos = new List<SubscriptionModuleDto>();

            /// Here I get just 1 model
            List<SoftwareModule> calcModuleModels = 
                await _managementContext.SoftwareModule.Where(s => s.SoftwareId == (int)softwareId && s.Part.Id == 70)
                    .Include(s => s.Software)
                    .Include(s => s.Part)
                    .ToListAsync();

            /// If I execute the next code, the model from the query above will be tracked as deleted.
            List<SoftwareModule> pmModuleModules = 
                await _managementContext.SoftwareModule.Where(s => s.SoftwareId == subscriptionModel.PackageIdProjectManagement && s.Part.Id == 70)
                .Include(s => s.Software)
                .Include(s => s.Part)
                .ToListAsync();

            // here I filter the unchanged entities / models.
            foreach (var model in calcModuleModels)
            {
                if (_managementContext.Entry(model).State != EntityState.Unchanged)
                {
                    bool x = true;
                    throw new Exception("model will be deleted");
                }
            }```

How does EF code know that the records will be deleted? How does EF core work? I don't understand.
````

Comment: That sounds confusing as to why the entity state for the first item might change, though entry.State != EntityState.Unchanged does not mean it will be deleted unless entry.State == EntityState.Deleted. If the Context is configured to not track entities (I.e. turning off change auto detection) then the entity state would come back as "Detached" not "Unchanged".  Is there other code that you have simplified out of your example, something that might replace a reference to the SoftwareModule in question where EF is treating it as an orphan deletion? It does sound like some strange behaviour.

Comment: Which version of EF exactly?

Comment: The problem is solved. The .Include(s.Part) had a one to one relationship instead of a one to many.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. The .Include(s.Part) had a one to one relationship instead of a one to many. –

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).